# Powertip mouse-on example does disappear after some seconds

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have a jquery.powertip function which does work. The only Problem I have is, that when the user hovers over the target div, the "helpbox" appears but only for a second or two... do u guys know a way to make the "helpbox" stay there?

heres the code i used:

```
$(function () {

    // mouse-on example
    var mouseOnDiv = $('#weiterbutton');
    var tipContent = $(
        '<p><b>Here is some content</b></p>' +
        '<p><a href="http://stevenbenner.com/">Maybe a link</a></p>');

    mouseOnDiv.data('powertipjq', tipContent);
    mouseOnDiv.powerTip();
});
```

Comment: stay there ? always show and dont hide on mouse leave?

Comment: @Manish
no, the helpbox should appear on mouse over & should hide when mouse ain't over the DIV anymore. At the moment, when you have the mouse over the DIV the box does appear. But only a second or so... I want the helpbox stay there as long as I do have my mouse over the div & hide as soon as I leave the DIV.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5zv5j/ working fine here

Comment: HI @Manish ! what js scripts should be included? the script works in your jsfiddle indeed but doesn't on my local machine.. I includded  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.powertip.js"></script> but still not working. Is there something else that should be added?

Comment: @LeahKwon Download the powertip plugin from  http://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/scripts/jquery.powertip.js and then include it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got something similar when I used Powertip on a div which contains an image.

The problem was solved once I use Powertip  directly on the image.

I think that the state of the mouse goes from "hover over the div" to "hover over the image inside the div" after a moment, and thus make the tooltip disappear.